# Qt programs have Greek fonts on one Debian account (QtConfig, Virtualbox and VLC)

Tags: debian, xfce, fonts, locale, qt

**Update:** I have created a new user via `adduser` and Virtualbox fonts are OK there. This does *not* solve my problem, however... I still don't know what is going on and I'd like my own user account to have the correct settings.

In my fresh install of Debian with Xfce, programs such as QtConfig, VLC and Virtualbox, which presumably use the Qt GUI framework, all have Greek fonts.

This is really annoying, and I'd like to change it to something understandable, preferably the system-wide font settings.

Here are some screenshots:

QtConfig: [image: QtConfig]
Virtualbox: [image: Virtualbox]
VLC: [image: VLC]

How can I solve this?

**Additional info:**

`locale` says:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

`egrep '^[^#]' /etc/locale.gen` says:

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Comment: Have you selected a greek locale/theme? [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/109531) it is described how you can reset all your kde settings.

Comment: I'm using Xfce.

Comment: What results do you got when you run `locale` and `egrep '^[^#]' /etc/locale.gen` on a terminal?

Comment: @MartínCanaval, see the edit, I ran the commands but mostly get "en_US - UTF-8"-like results, which seems to be correct.

Comment: Can you try to set the font manually as [here](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=19156#p19156) described.

Comment: Hey @jofel, that's for KDE, but I don't use KDE.

Comment: @Yannbane Sorry for the KDE stuff (a lot of programs use KDE at top of Qt even inside other window manager). In [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/dhESJFY.png) you can see the 2nd tab of QtConfig. Changing the font there could solve your problem.

Comment: Try adding `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and `LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8` to your `/etc/locale.conf` file. If after rebooting that doesn't fix the issue, try running virtualbox from a terminal with `(LANG=en_US.UTF-8 VirtualBox)` (or whatever the name of the executable is) and see if that changes anything. But most likely a bug report is in order.

Comment: This is definitely a Greek font rather than actual Greek script... the heading maps exactly to "Welcome to VirtualBox!"

Comment: @ChrisDown: yes, that is true. I can actually navigate through some menus because the characters look familiar.

Comment: @Yannbane: Why upgrade Qt? I don't think that's needed. Does it work with a test user?

Comment: You probably want to post that as a comment. I'm sorry, I haven't yet tried the new user method. I will soon.

Comment: @schaiba: it works with the test user, please see the update header in the question.

Comment: If so, please check your Qt settings on your original user.

Comment: Easier said than done, I'm afraid, @schaiba. The `Qt 4 settings` program itself has those fonts (see the screenshots), so it's hard to navigate. Could I change it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a locale problem.

I don't know Greek but I can tell from your screenshot that it's perfectly normal English. It quite clearly says "Welcome to VirtualBox", there's a button that says "New", the one next to it suspiciously looks like "Settings", there are several "the" and other English words. If it actually was Greek I'd expect it to look very different.

So it's not locale and it's not Greek but English.

I suppose you have installed or selected some Joke font on your system which displays ABC characters in Greek equivalents. Unfortunately I am not fluent enough in Qt configuration nor do I know which font that could be to point you directly to the solution.

Maybe it will help you anyway.

Comment: Yeah, we have already figured that out, but +1 for that package information.

Comment: You could go for a divide and conquer approach. See if you can reproduce the issue if you copy all config files (the hidden files and dirs) to another user account. If that reproduces the issue, delete one half of the files. If the issue goes away, delete the other half. Rinse and repeat until you're left with the culprit file. It's annoying and a last resort if you have no other pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your `/etc/default/locale` file, [maybe also on](http://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Standard) `/etc/environment`.

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

More adequately add the following to `/etc/profile`

```
: ${LANG:=en_US.UTF-8}; export LANG
: ${LC_ALL:=en_US.UTF-8}; export LC_ALL
```

If after rebooting that doesn't fix the issue, try running virtualbox from a terminal like this

```
(export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; VirtualBox)
```

or whatever the name of the executable is, and see if that changes anything. I read [somewhere](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt4-x11/+bug/918758) that qt 4.7 had locales issues, fixed on the 4.8 version.

**Edit**, as Chris Brown mentioned on the comments, Setting the `LC_ALL` variable globally is not a graceful solution. It's more intended as a temporary workaround in case the problem is the bug on the 4.7 version. This change should be undone if that is not the problem or if it's fixed after upgrading to qt 4.8.

Comment: Sadly, none of the things you had suggested have worked...

Comment: Try creating a test user and see if issues persist.

Comment: Setting LC_ALL as a global override is not a graceful way to handle this situation.

Comment: @ChrisDown, well, it doesn't work either way.

Comment: @schaiba - how does one upgrade Qt? AFAIK it's a C++ library, so I doubt it has a runtime (shared libraries?).

Answer (score 0):

Try backing up or clearing your `~/.config/Trolltech.conf`

Comment: Backed it up and then I `rm`'d it. The fonts were still undesired, but the file appeared again...

Comment: Yep, confirming now: `diff` of the test user's `Trolltech.conf` and mine is none.

Comment: Please paste the output of 'env | grep -i lang'

Comment: Additional possibilities: `~/.config/Trolltech/`, `~/.config/fontconfig/`, `~/.kde4/`
The font is called "Standard Symbols L", maybe grepping $HOME helps.

Comment: @schaiba:LANG=en_US.UTF-8 (newline) LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8.

Comment: @t-8ch: I have none of those directories...

Comment: And Gtk (`gtk-demo`) works?
Try chaning it with qtconfig
Second tab, first dropdown. Any other option.
Close the window. Leftmost button in confirmation box is `Yes` (Could also be rightmost)

Answer (score 0):

as root:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Sadly that didn't work.